SQL Server XML column is string in .NET using SqlDataReader
Why if in SQL Server, I have a column defined as XML type, and in .NET with SqlDataReader/SqlDataAdapter I have a string?
See the example in the screenhsot, cast c1 in XML, but .NET gets a string.
I tried also with XML column, always string.

This my code
SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("select *, convert(xml, c1) c6 from tempdb..t1", conn);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
new SqlDataAdapter(sc).Fill(dt);

How can I recognize a XML result to cast only when necessary?

That's how it reads it. You can use GetSqlXml if you have a reader https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getsqlxml?view=sqlclient-dotnet-standard-5.2 but otherwise it will just turn it into a string.

how can i recognize a xml result?

reader.GetDataTypeName tells you the type. By the way your code in the screenshot rather ominously uses both SqlDataAdapterandSqlDataReaderwhich means you are probably executing the command twice. You are also missingusing` to dispose everything.

@Charlieface: perfetct, this was i needed!

SOLUTION
as suggested by @Charlieface, instead of
dr[n].GetType() // get System.String (.net type)

i used
dr.GetDataTypeName(n) // get xml (sql type)

